# Determine if template exists in emberjs

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, coffeescript

My emberjs app uses the following line in my ember-cli-build.js file

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

along with some code like this (coffeescript)

```
define("floorplan-viewer/templates/#{templateName}", ['exports'], (exports) ->
  exports['default'] = Ember.HTMLBars.compile(temlateText)
)
```

to enable dynamic template creation.

Now I need to be able to determine if i.e. "floorplan-viewer/templates/custom-template-001" exists.  How would I inspect the environment to see if such a template has been created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
window.require.entries["floorplan-viewer/templates/#{templateName}"] != null
```